# assign Ember component variable with a Map

Tags: javascript, dictionary, ember.js, components

I have an Ember Component, Inside it, I declared a variable and after that I put a map inside the variable like this:

```
const SubscriptionForm = Ember.Component.extend({
     messagesFilter: Ember.Map.create(),
     
      init() {
          this.set('messagesFilter', this.getMessagesFilter());
```

and this is the getMessagesFilter function:

```
  getMessagesFilter() {
     let map = new Map();
     for (var i = 0; i < this.get('availableMessages').length; i++){
       let array = [];
       map.set(this.get('availableMessages').get(i), array);
     }

   return map;
 },
```

I verified that getMessagesFilter return a map with data inside.
I don't undestand why when I do *console.log(this.get('messagesFilter'))* returns *undefined*.

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Where do you put this log?

Comment: at the init function, after this.set('messagesFilter', this.getMessagesFilter())

Comment: Something seems fishy. Any chance you can create a reproduction on ember-twiddle.com?